# apache appending port number to url on ssl request

Tags: apache

I am trying to access a url like https://abcd/test and it is getting redirected with port number https://abcd:9011/test/. Since it is routing through load balancer, it is not required to use the actual webserver port number and other pages are loading without port number(using default port). But if access it using http:// it works fine. Please help if I am missing anything in ssl.conf

Comment: That is not the apache http server doing that itself. Most likely it is some logic of the application served here. Many try to auto detect their network topological location to create absolute URLs. From the point of view of the application that port number is correct and required... Take a look if there is some configuration option to set a "base URL" for that application.

Comment: I am trying a direct call to apache. Just giving like this <https://abcd/test> which goes to apache and in between only LB is there. I removed all the rewrite rules and tried with no luck. Strangely if I add a trailing slash, <https://abcd/test/> it works fine and also it is working fine with http as well.

Comment: That points to the index feature of the backend server.

Comment: Yes, and it is not working because of port is getting added. Because abcd expects only port 443.

Comment: The backend server listens on port 9011. From its point of view `https://abcd:9011/test/` is the correct URL. It does not know about the front end server ("load balancer"). Since aparently the rewriting is done by the index module _on the backend server_ the port is added.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will check this but one question then how it works normally when I specify / which forcing for index and also works fine in http

Comment: In that case apparently no rewriting is done on the backend server which does sound plausible to me. Keep in mind though that I cannot look over your shoulder. I do not know anything about your setup. So I may well be totally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Added ServerName in virtual host and that resolved the issue.

ServerName abcd

Thank you arkascha for replying to the post.